# eXist XQuery wrap variable in CDATA

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I was wondering if it is possible to wrap the contents of a variable (that might contain messy html) into a cdata section.

I am using XQuery with eXist and I just can't seem to get it working.

I tried

```
<![CDATA[ $data ]]>
<![CDATA[ {$data} ]]>
```

In both cases the variable is not replaced by its contents, but remains $data and {$data} respectively.

I also tried using concat and other string functions, but these resulted in `<![CDATA[` becoming `&lt;![CDATA[`.

The $data contains http get/post data from an html wysiwyg editor.

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";

let $data := request:get-parameter("content" , "")
return <![CDATA[ {$data} ]]>
```

Does anyone now how it should be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Literal CDATA sections are just that. And there is no standard instruction for output dynamic CDATA sections nor `cdata-section-elements` declaration as in XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

@Alejandro is right.  See Priscilla Walmsley's [XQuery](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006341) book pp. 280-281.  "All of the text in a CDATA section is taken literally; it is not possible to include enclosed expressions in a CDATA section."

If you want to deal with "messy HTML" by fixing malformed bits, you may wish to check out the NekoHTML-powered [util:parse-html()](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/util/parse-html) function.  Pass the messy HTML string, and you'll get well-formed XML node on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode some well-formed but arbitrary HTML as a string, for example to include in a KML description, use util:serialise()

eg.

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace util="http://exist-db.org/xquery/util";

let $data := <div><h1>stuff</h1><a href="url"> <img src="image"/></a></div>
return
   util:serialize($data,"method=xml"))
```

The effect is the same as if the XML were enclosed in CDATA, with the reserved XML characters encoded.